# How does Hotspot Java/JVM store memory?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, jvm-hotspot

Is there anywhere that a hostspot JVM process stores memory besides these places:

- perm gen
- tenured generation
- eden space
- from space
- to space
- code cache

That is to say: What possible ways are there that the hotspot process can reserve & commit memory on a machine such that said memory would **not** show up in the statistics for one of those places?

Some answers I can think of (let me know if these are true):

- virtual memory used for thread stacks are not represented in those numbers
- any loaded dlls  or files.

EDIT:

some other answers given:

- java.exe itself
- JNI methods could allocate memory itself
- any native code (eg. from dlls) could allocate memory.
- general JVM metadata for running itself.

Comment: Native code will allocate its own memory. This strictly speaking runs outside the JVM but it will cause your program to use more memory then it is reporting in these numbers.

Comment: Keep in mind that all the above "spaces" are representative of one particular family of JVMs (Hotspot) -- there is nothing that says that every JVM has an "eden space" or a "to space".  The three main spaces present in just about any JVM process are the main object heap, the heap used for class info and code, and the "non-Java" heap used by the JVM internals.  (One could argue that the execution stack is another "space", or count it as "non-Java".)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct so far (DLLs include all JNI libraries and whatever memory they've allocated).  The VM also has its own code (e.g., the contents of `java`), bookkeeping information *about* the memory that's allocated to Java programs, and potentially memory used by VM agents.  Basically, what you described in your first list are the items that make up the "running memory" of the virtual machine; the rest of the JVM's memory are all of the items that represent the virtual machine's "hardware", such as the libraries that connect it to the OS's networking, graphics, and so on.

Comment: Would [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366556%28VS.85%29.aspx) also not show up in heap/codecache statistics?

Comment: Are you talking about memory-mapped files in Java?  The only way to do that is with `Buffer`s, but in that case, you would see some memory usage for the Java fields for the `Buffer`, but not for the mapped memory region. Whether and how the OS charges the mapped memory to the JVM process depends on the OS.

Comment: Wouldn't it have to charge the mapped memory to JVM virtual memory space? How else can the process even read it then?

Comment: Memory accounting varies from OS to OS, and how memory mapping (including executable code) is handled is especially variable. Accounting isn't the same as actually setting up the descriptor tables, which does have to be done for any storage-backed memory.